# how to change output color of powershell command

Tags: powershell, colors, powershell-7.2

I want to change the color of output in Powershell intelligently, but it seems there is no way. For example: "grep --help" would give me help information in white color, but I want to highlight some words like "NO", "Except for" and short/long arguments. The original color engine only works in cmdlet implement; they cannot process the color of other program's output. So, is there a way to call my callback function before the output of a command is print to the console so that I can change something easily?
For example:
My powershell shows "rg -h" like:
[image]

But another opensource terminal holding powershell shows "rg -h" like:
[image]

how to make my native powershell behaves just like the later?

Comment: This [`Out-HostColored`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/243ea8297e7db0e1c03a67ce4b1e765d) script from**[@
mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)** might do where you look for.

Comment: but how to do that automatically? I don't want to add | Out-Host-Colored after each command.